# Counting the value when calling a function

Tags: php

I need some help as I am new on this. I am working on a function to add the day value that start from 0 to 6. I want to count it up the value for each day so I can connect to each url for each day, but on my code it will only show the value as 0 for each day.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$channels = json_decode(file_get_contents('channels.json'), true);
$day = 0;

function get_shows($channel_id, DateTime $dt, $duration=1440, $skip_finished = true) 
{
    $url = 'http://example.comapi/GS?cid=' . $channel_id . '&offset=+00.00&day=' .$day++;
    echo $url;
    $day++;
}


if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !isset($channels[$_GET['id']])) 
{
    //some random code.....
}
else
{
    // today + 6 following days
   for($day=0; $day<=6; $day++) 
   {
      // display date      
      echo '<h3>', $dt->format('Y-m-d (l)'), '</h3>';

      // display shows
      foreach(get_shows($channel_id, $dt, $duration) as $show) 
      {

      }
      $dt->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
      $dt->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
2018-05-04 (Friday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0

2018-05-05 (Saturday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0

2018-05-06 (Sunday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0

2018-05-07 (Monday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0

2018-05-08 (Tuesday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0

2018-05-09 (Wednesday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0

2018-05-10 (Thursday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
2018-05-04 (Friday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=0

2018-05-05 (Saturday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=1

2018-05-06 (Sunday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=2

2018-05-07 (Monday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=3

2018-05-08 (Tuesday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=4

2018-05-09 (Wednesday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=5

2018-05-10 (Thursday)
http://example.com/api/GS?cid=44630&offset=+00.00&day=6
```

Can you please show me an example how I can add up the value for each day that start from 0 to 6 when I am calling on a function??

Comment: `global $day` inside get_show will help immensely. Also you're incrementing $day twice in the method when obviously you should only do it once.

Comment: thank you, can you please post the answer of what I should use so I would mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a function, variables only have local scope unless you explicitly say otherwise.

```php
$day = 0;

function get_shows($channel_id, DateTime $dt, $duration=1440, $skip_finished = true) 
{
    global $day;
    $url = 'http://example.comapi/GS?cid=' . $channel_id . '&offset=+00.00&day=' .$day++;
     echo $url;
     // don't need this either as you've already post incremented $day
     // $day++;
 }
```

As others have stated, using global variables is not a good technique and you should really be passing `$day` into the method.

Comment: oh thank you very much for this as it is working great. Problem are now solved!

Comment: No problem, but look at the other answers as whilst my answer fixes your problem, the other answers are better programming solutions

Answer (score 0):

Either use the global that exist by adding `global $day` in your function:

```
function get_shows($channel_id, DateTime $dt, $duration=1440, $skip_finished = true) 
{
    global $day;
    $url = 'http://example.comapi/GS?cid='.$channel_id.'&offset=+00.00&day='.$day;
    echo $url;
}
```

Also remove the increments to `$day` as they are not needed, your already did this in your loop. Or add an extra parameter and pass `$day` into your function and use that:

```
get_shows($channel_id, DateTime $dt, $day, $duration=1440, $skip_finished = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$day` into the function as a parameter. You're already looping over it but not using it. Your other option is to declare the variable as global, or static within the function body, [both of which are not sensible choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions).

Change

```
function get_shows($channel_id, DateTime $dt, $duration=1440, $skip_finished = true)
```

to

```
function get_shows($channel_id, DateTime $dt, $day, $duration=1440, $skip_finished = true);
```

and call it using

```
get_shows($channel_id, $dt, $day, $duration)
```

You don't need to increment the variable within the function as well as the loop - let the function do one thing, based on the parameters passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: scope!

You are trying to access a variable that exists outside the function, which does not work in PHP. Each time you call $day++, $day does not exist, so PHP will try to initialize it with the value 0. That's why every url has day=0 in it.

using the "global" keyword is not recommended, because it will eventually lead to very messy code, which can be hard to debug.

I'd recommend something like this (simplified version):

```
function getShowUrl($channel_id, $day) 
{
    return 'http://example.comapi/GS?cid=' . $channel_id . '&offset=+00.00&day=' .$day;
}

for($day = 0; $day < 7; $day++) {
    echo getShowUrl($channel_id,$day);
}
```

Using echo inside a function is usually not recommended. Using return enables you to reuse the function for another implementation.